# Generating Unique Set of Random Integers

Tags: java, random, duplicates

This is my first time building an app and I have a problem. I'm making this app that will generate random numbers only sometimes it shows me the number twice. This is not what I'm aiming for so how can program it that it will show random numbers without duplicates?

This is my code btw:

```
    package rando.mizer;

    import java.util.Random;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class RandomizerFinalActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */   
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            Button buttonGenerate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            final EditText aantalT= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            final EditText laagsteT = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            final EditText hoogsteT = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            final EditText uitvoerT = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4); 



            buttonGenerate.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

               public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    final int aantal = Integer.parseInt(aantalT.getText().toString());
                    final int laagste = Integer.parseInt(laagsteT.getText().toString());
                    final int hoogste = Integer.parseInt(hoogsteT.getText().toString());

                    uitvoerT.setText("");
                    Random r = new Random();

                    int aNumber;
                    String build = "";


                for(int i = 0; i < aantal; i++) {
                    aNumber = laagste + r.nextInt(hoogste + 1 - laagste);
                    build += aNumber + ",\n";
                }

                    uitvoerT.setText(build);


              }

            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: random is random, it may happen that it generates the same number more than once. you could generate the numbers in a loop assigning them to a Set, which will guarantee you won't have duplicates.

Comment: Of how many numbers are we talking about?

Comment: There is not an exact number of random numbers. The person using the app can say in aantalT how many random numbers he or she would like to have. I tried this:
                         ArrayList<Integer> dubbel=new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    for(int i = 0; i < aantal; i++) {
                     aNumber = laagste + r.nextInt(hoogste + 1 - laagste);
                     while (dubbel.contains(aNumber)){
                     aNumber = r.nextInt(hoogste + 1 - laagste);
                      }
                      build += aNumber + "\n";

only it doen't work.

Comment: The solution from ARRG and mine do just what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Using Collections.shuffle is a great idea, but you don't need to shuffle all the numbers. It would be more efficient to use:

```
// return nNumbers distinct values from low to (high - 1)
public List<Integer> getRandoms(int low, int high, int nNumbers) {
    int range = high - low;
    List<Integer> workArray = new ArrayList(range);
    for (Integer i = low; i < high; i++)
        workArray.add(i);

    // Put the chosen values at the start of the array one by one 
    // (and then do not touch the start of the array).
    int pseudoStartIndex = 0;
    while (pseudoStartIndex < nNumbers) {
        int randomIndex = pseudoStartIndex + 
                          random.nextInt(range - pseudoStartIndex); 
        Integer tempSwap = workArray.get(pseudoStartIndex);
        workArray.set(pseudoStartIndex, workArray.get(randomIndex));
        workArray.set(randomIndex, tempSwap);
        pseudoStartIndex++;
    }
    return workArray.subList(0, nNumbers);
}
```

It's basically the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), but applied to only a few elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you are using always the same seed, so the chances of generating the same number are very high, first you need to understand that is impossible to generate a pure random number, what Java give you is a pretty decent mechanism but relies on the seed.

A common practice is to use the current date time in miliseconds so, if you do:

```
new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())
```

You will find that you don't get duplicates. You can try it with this code:

```
public static void main (String... args){
   for (int i=0; i<10000; i++){
       try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
       Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
       System.out.println(random.nextInt());

   }
}
```

Comment: this will still produce duplicates, just not in the same order

Comment: Hi Jarrod, thanks for repeating in your comment what I have stated in my answer! That's great mate! So tell us... Do you have a solution for a real random generator? Maybe you can win the nove prize for that! Obviously this won't produce a unique list of nunmbers, but I am pretty sure I would run for quite a loooooooooooooooooong time before it produces a duplicate... Is almost only based on the assumption that some miliseconds go by from call to call...

Comment: Just ran it in 10000 repetition loop with a Thread.sleep(100) and guess what, not even one duplicate...

Comment: a "real" random number generator emits duplicates by design, there is nothing not real or wrong about the random number generator that Java supplies. A Unique Set of numbers randomly generated is a different story.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to randomly pick numbers without repeats from a known set, as is done for example in a lottery. This approach would work, provided the set isn't too large (note that it will fail if count is larger than the amount of numbers).

```
/** Will pick `count` numbers randomly from the set of numbers between
 * startNumber (included) and endNumber (excluded). */
public static Collection<Integer> randomPick(int startNumber, int endNumber, int count) {
    // Generate a list of all numbers from start to endNumber
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = startNumber; i < endNumber; i++) {
        numbers.add(i);
    }

    // Shuffle them
    Collections.shuffle(numbers);

    // Pick count items.
    return numbers.subList(0, count);
}
```

Comment: you should use a `Set` instead of a `List`

Comment: You can't Collections.shuffle on a Set.

Comment: it makes no sense, just use a `Set` that avoids duplicates by design.

Comment: Sorry but your comment doesn't make sense. How would you retrieve a random subset of elements from a Set ?

Comment: Set does not admit duplicates. Also you  go for a SecureRandom

Comment: Set does not admit duplicates, but think of TreeSet or HashSet, if you use them you will get the same order of results every time you try.

Comment: Collections.shuffle only takes a List as argument anyway; it would not make sense on a Set.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh : How is that relevant ? In the case of natural numbers, the order in a TreeSet would be the natural ordering of the elements, and then you would have to hand-code your own shuffle routine. As far as I know, HashSet would also give you the natural ordering, or at best a non-natural but still predictable ordering, not a random one.

Comment: I was meaning that there's no need to shuffle. If you use a Set to store the random numbers, you will get a collection of unique random numbers. The order of the elements is not an issue, it may or may not be the same as the insertion order. What he wants to achieve is to have a fixed number of integers, randomly generated. If you don't use a Set you have to implement some sort of checking for duplicates, which is exactly what a HashSet does with the help of hash keys.

Comment: Your algorithm won't work if he wants non contiguous numbers. With Random you have more control.

Comment: @vulkanino : 1) inserting random numbers into a set until the set has the required size can take an unpredictable time. This is especially true if the aim is to get a complete random ordering of a known set of numbers (e.g. if you want to randomize the numbers from 1 to 1000, inserting the last number has a 1/1000 chance of happening). 2) How do you enumerate the contents of your set ? As I said, both HashSet and TreeSet won't give you a satisfying ordering !

Comment: @ARRG 1) is true, still my comment on controlling the randomness applies. 2) you have iterators to cycle through the elements, unless you want to list them in insertion order (but why?).

Comment: @vulkanino : iterators aren't good enough. Try it for yourself: http://www.ipaste.org/g8

Answer (score 0):

It would be much better if you create and initialize (it with a seed) the Random object once, instead of creating the random on each call to your Listener, it would be less likely to have duplicate numbers.

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.Set;

Set<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<Integer>(10); // do you know how many elements do you need?
boolean elementNotThere;
do {
    int myInt = r.nextInt(hoogste + 1 - laagste);
    elementNotThere = mySet.add(myInt);
} while ( ! elementNotThere );
```

Comment: @JarrodRoberson didn't try it, may have a couple or typo, but I don't agree with the -1

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I thank yatskevich and myself. Not you that are not being constructive.

Comment: It still makes no sense as it is: it just stops when it reached a duplicate element, which will mean either too few or too many elements.  And the name of the boolean indicates the opposite of what it actually does.

Comment: @toto2 no, it continues to generate a random until it can be inserted in the set. about the name of the variable, I've changed it.

Comment: @vulkanino If `add` fails because of a duplicate, elementExists is set to false and you get out of the loop.

Comment: @vulkanino Still no good: you add one number and elementExists is set to true and you get out of the loop.

Comment: What is childish about down voting a supposed *answer* that is **wrong**, even after many edits ...

Comment: @toto2 the while loop is supposed to avoid duplicate random values, of course it should live inside another loop to create N values as he wants.